# Number of different distributions of hands to $4$ players

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

*There are many many at first sight, similar questions about decks but none it's about this.*

I want to find the different way to distribute $4$ hands of $13$ cards each, to $4$ different players.

I am thinking that we can actually split the deck in $4$ teams of $13$ cards in $\frac{52!}{(13!)^4}$ ways, but we also know that there are only $13$ different cards each in $4$ copies so we need to divide by $(4!)^{13}$ .

**Final answer** : $\frac{52!}{(4!)^{13}(13!)^4}$.

Am I **right/wrong and why?**

A friend of mine supports that the answer  is :$\binom{52}{1}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}$ but I think this approach treats all the $52$ cards as distinct.

Comment: unfortunately you are wrong , bt.w not $52$ , it must have been $52!$. Moreover , all cards are distinct , thats why you are wrong

Comment: Think the cards are like people in family, when you say card $4$ , it is like surname but the cards whose surname is $4$  also have names such as diamond , clubs , hearts , spades.Do you see all people in a family as same because of the fact that they have same surname ? :)

Comment: Are you sure your friend's answer was not $\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}$?

Comment: @Bulbasaur yes that's was a typo. thank you for the rest of the insights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $4$ players are $A,B,C,D$, either consider

- first giving $13$ cards each to $A$, then $B$, then $C$, then $D$, so $\binom{52}{13}\binom{39}{13}\binom{26}{13}\binom{13}{13}$
- or considering all permutations of $52$ cards laid out in a line, and dividing by the permutations of $13$ in each hand, so $\frac{52!}{(13!)^{4}}$

Comment: so my mistake was treating cards with the same symbol as not distinct?

Comment: Yes, the ace of spades , eg is different from the ace of hearts.